# Where is PageWriteback defined in the 4.9 Linux kernel source?

Tags: linux-kernel

[A search for PageWriteback in 4.9](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.9/ident/PageWriteback) results in: "undefined identifier", yet
[a search for PageWriteback in 2.6.25](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v2.6.25/ident/PageWriteback) shows that it is defined there.

Why is `PageWriteback` in use in 4.9 but I can't find a definition for it?

Comment: Your title has a question, but the body seems to be two statements. What are you asking?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Why `PageWriteback` use in 4.9 but can't found define of it?

Comment: So you're saying that a particular identifier is in use, but you can't find where it's being defined?

Comment: @JeffSchaller `So you're saying that a particular identifier is in use, but you can't find where it's being defined?` Yes.

Comment: See if my edit captured your intent, please.

Comment: @JeffSchaller In fact this question not only for `PageWriteback` ,when I try understand Linux kernel sources,many identifier that I can't found define where as this question.

Comment: I think trying to ask for *any* identifier would be too broad or unclear -- focusing this question on one identifier gives it a chance of an answer (as we've already seen).

Comment: @JeffSchaller I can't understand you said "Tom"  what is that?  I'm not mean any ,I'm mean some identifier more then one but not any or all.

Comment: @JeffSchaller unless something like `ctags` would index the identifiers. (Haven't used it. Have heard of it. There must be newer alternatives, surely?)

Comment: It seems to me like the free-electrons does something like that, @roaima; unfortunately for this particular case, the identifier is stitched together by the pre-processor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is (along with many other PageXXX things) defined in `include/linux/page-flags.h`, but the definition is obscured by the use of macros. See the macro `TESTPAGEFLAG` in the above file.

In particular, this [definition of the TESTPAGEFLAG macro](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.9/source/include/linux/page-flags.h#L189):

```
#define TESTPAGEFLAG(uname, lname, policy)              \
static __always_inline int Page##uname(struct page *page)       \
    { return test_bit(PG_##lname, &policy(page, 0)->flags); }
```

combined with this [call to TESTPAGEFLAG with the Writeback parameters](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.9/source/include/linux/page-flags.h#L296):

```
TESTPAGEFLAG(Writeback, writeback, PF_NO_COMPOUND)
```

Answer (score 1):

The general question stuck with me, so I thought I'd add an answer as to how I might go about finding an arbitrary identifier in the Linux kernel.

Download a version of the kernel source (or install your distribution's linux-kernel source package), and extract it:

```
wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.9.39.tar.xz
tar xf linux-4.9.39.tar.xz
cd linux-4.9.39
```

Create a minimal .config, just to make a compilable kernel:

```
make menuconfig # just exit and save
```

Key step: [compile the kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/kbuild.txt) with the `-save-temps` gcc flag so that it saves the intermediate pre-processor files:

```
make KCFLAGS=-save-temps
```

The compilation process will drop `*.i` files in the current directory.
Find any file where the identifier is defined; I picked the same identifier here, for ease of comparison, but the process would work for any other identifier; I picked zbud.i only because I liked the filename:

```
grep PageWriteback *.i
...
zbud.i:static inline __attribute__((no_instrument_function)) __attribute__((always_inline)) int PageWriteback(struct page *page) { return (__builtin_constant_p((PG_writeback)) ? constant_test_bit((PG_writeback), (&({ ((void)(sizeof(( long)(0 && PageCompound(page))))); page;})->flags)) : variable_test_bit((PG_writeback), (&({ ((void)(sizeof(( long)(0 && PageCompound(page))))); page;})->flags))); }
...
```

Open the file for viewing, scroll to the identifier in question, then search up/backwards in the file for a line that starts with `#` to see where the definition came from:

```
# 255 "./include/linux/page-flags.h"
```

which points us to the [same source file that Nick found before](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381993/117549).

Alternatively, you could search for the include lines and/or the identifier, then delete all the trailing lines; the last line of output will be the file where the identifier was defined:

```
grep -E '^# |PageWriteback' zbud.i | sed '/PageWriteback/,$d' | tail -n 1
...
# 74 "./include/linux/page-flags.h"
# 108 "./include/linux/page-flags.h"
# 255 "./include/linux/page-flags.h"
```

Comment: `# 255 "./include/linux/page-flags.h"` seem isn't [definition of the TESTPAGEFLAG macro](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.9/source/include/linux/page-flags.h#L189).I can't understand you how to found [define](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.9/source/include/linux/page-flags.h#L189) by use your result.

Comment: Nick [did an awesome job](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/381993/117549) finding that particular definition; all I did was extend their idea to ("expanding" / combining) the pre-processor tokens to the rest of the kernel so that it'd be easier to find the next one you were curious about.